# How to add variable inside jQuery selector

Tags: jquery

Good Day

I want to add a variable into a jQuery selector, but the syntax is wrong:

```
var c = $(this).attr('class');

            if ($('#articleThumb ul li img').hasClass(c)) {
                $('#articleThumb ul li img.'+c').clone().appendTo('#articleFeatured');
            }
```

the class

**img.class** is a variable and not a constant like **img.birds** for example...

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your quotes are off, notice the stray one after `c`. It should be:

```
$('#articleThumb ul li img.' + c)
```

Comment: One more question: If there is more than one element that has a specific class, how do I append only the first one?

Comment: @DavidVanStaden You can use `eq(0)` in your selector, such that: 

`$('#articleThumb ul li img.' + c + ':eq(0)')`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply concatenate the variable with selector string. Remove the extra single quote at the end of c in selector.

*Change*

```
 $('#articleThumb ul li img.'+c')
```

*To*

```
$('#articleThumb ul li img.' + c)
```

Comment: One more question: If there is more than one element that has a specific class, how do I append only the first one?

Comment: $('.classname:first') will give you first element

Comment: yeah but the loop that the append function will run each time a specific class is found...so it will not listen to the :first selector inside the append function...since the append function will execute again

Comment: Sorry, could not get you, can you make a fiddle?

Comment: As Grant Thomas pointed out - you can use: $('#articleThumb ul li img.' + c + ':eq(0)') to prevent copies/redundancy

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're adding an additional `'`

```
$('#articleThumb ul li img.' + c)
```